# Return to previous label in batch ('goto' command)

Tags: batch-file

For example,

```
@echo off
goto main

:main
echo Select:
echo 1) Goto label 1
echo 2) Goto label 2
set /p choice=
if %choice% == 1 goto label1
if %choice% == 2 goto label2

:label1
echo Will now direct you to label2
echo Press any key to go to label2
pause >nul

:label2 [PROBLEM HERE]
echo Type 'N' or 'E' and press Enter to go back to label1 or exit.
set /p choice2=
if %choice2% == N goto label1
if %choice2% == E exit
```

Please ignore the part where it says 'goto main', I know it isn't necessary but I've got used to it.

The "PROBLEM HERE" indicates the part where I want the batch to return to label1, without actually typing the code to specify to go back to previous label, as sometimes I might need label1 to work something to go to label2 and work another thing, then go back to label1 again to continue its business.

Answer (score 25):

`goto` has no "Return".
But you can `call` a part of your script:

```
@echo off
echo main program
call :label1
echo main program
call :label2
echo main program

pause
exit /b

:label1
echo subroutine
goto :eof

echo never reached

:label2
echo sub two
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you haven't said **why** you have a problem in the position you claim.

The solution

```
@echo off
goto main

:main
echo Select:
echo 1) Goto label 1
echo 2) Goto label 2
set /p choice=
if %choice% == 1 goto label1
if %choice% == 2 goto label2

:label1
echo Will now direct you to label2
echo Press any key to go to label2
pause >nul

:label2
echo Press any key to go from label2 to label1
pause >nul
goto label1
```

would seem far too obvious.

```dos
@echo off
goto main

:main
echo Select:
echo 1) Goto label 1
echo 2) Goto label 2
set /p choice=
if %choice% == 1 goto label1
if %choice% == 2 call :label2

:label1
echo Will now direct you to label2
echo Press any key to go to label2
pause >nul

:label2
echo Reached label2 - Press any key to go from label2 to label1
pause >nul
goto :eof
```

where the colons **<kbd>:</kbd>eof** and call **<kbd>:</kbd>label2** are required (meaning 'special label end-of-file understood by CMD`and`internal subroutine` respectively.

However, some people ar under the impression that reaching a label terminates a batch routine in the same way as reaching the end of a paragraph or the `}` in `C` or `end;` in `Pascal`. It does not. Batch just charges on to the next sequential statement, like assembler.

I say this because your original code has no apparent way of terminating - on an entry of something other than `1` or `2` for instance, it would just run on through label1 and then through label2 - and if label2 goes back to label1, then you have an infinite loop.

One more item: If you are entering a string with a `set/p`, then there's no saying that the data entered doesn't contain <kbd>Spaces</kbd>. The way to get over that is to `"enclose the strings on both sides of the comparison operator in quotes"` - that is, double-quotes `'not single quotes'` If the user simply presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> then the `if %choice% == 1 goto label1` would be interpreted as `if == 1 goto label1` (since the variable `choice` would not be set) and this would generate a syntax error.

Oh - and `choice` isn't the best name for a variable (however logical and descriptive) since it's the name of a standard `CMD` utility.

From the prompt, try

```
choice /?
```

which might give you ideas about other methods of obtaining a er, choice...

Comment: Yeah sorry, I forgot to add in a way to exit the batch file. As for the command "set /p", I always get lost with this and don't know how to solve it in order _not_ to make the user press Enter without typing anything. Finally, for the "choice" command, I did not know there is such a command, but don't worry, I just use this for an example, I mostly use "set /p **num**" or "set /p **no**". Looks like the "choice" command might be pretty useful to display choices, hmm... Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Set variable=label1` or `Set variable=main` or `Set variable=EOF` before branching and use

```
goto :%variable%
```

to loop back or restart, or quit.

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear to me what you want, but it sounds as if you are looking for a sub-routine which can be done using a `call`

```
@echo off
goto main

:main
  echo Select:
  echo 1) Goto label 1
  echo 2) Goto label 2
  set /p choice=

  if %choice% == 1 goto label1
  if %choice% == 2 goto label2

  goto :eof 

:label1
  echo Will now direct you to label2
  echo Press any key to go to label2
  pause >nul
  call :label2

  goto :eof

:label2
  echo Reached label2
  goto :eof
```