# Batch file goto then return technique

Tags: batch-file

I am having difficulty trying to return after a goto instruction:

```
@echo off 
cls 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

:10
set watitle=10
title %watitle%
goto :installscreen
pause

:20
set watitle=20
title %watitle%
goto :installscreen
pause

:30
set watitle=30
title %watitle%
goto :installscreen
pause

exit

:installscreen
echo.
echo ===============================================================================
echo  %watitle%
echo ===============================================================================
echo.
goto :eof
```

When you run it, the variable is set and printed correctly (:10) but then I am not able to "return" to the point where the subroutine is called and run the following part (:20).

Do you have some hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Call` you can also send parameters with each:

```bat
@Echo Off
Call :InstallScreen 10
Pause
Call :InstallScreen 20
Pause
Call :InstallScreen 30
Pause
Exit

:InstallScreen
ClS
Title %1
Echo(
Echo ===============================================================================
Echo  %1
Echo ===============================================================================
Echo(
GoTo :EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

I apologize,
I just found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21074620/8745542)

Thanks [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan)

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

:10
set watitle=10
title  %watitle%
call :installscreen
pause

:20
set watitle=20
title  %watitle%
call :installscreen
pause

:30
set watitle=30
title  %watitle%
call :installscreen
pause

exit

:installscreen
echo.
echo ===============================================================================
echo  %watitle%
echo ===============================================================================
echo.
goto :eof
```